# MongoDB - format response

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that looks something like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "title": "dummy title",
    "settings": [
            {
                "type": "light",
                "status": "enabled"
            },
            {
                "type": "flare",
                "status": "disabled"
            },
            {
                "type": "toolbar",
                "status": "endbale"
            }
        ]
  }
]
```

I wanna create a query to fetch the document but with only the types of the active settings in an array, for example, in the above case the result should be:

```
[
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "title": "dummy title",
      "enabled_settings": ["light", "toolbar"]
    }
  ]
```

How can I achieve something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$reduce` in projection part, `$cond` condition will check if status is enabled then concat and in last return vlaue,

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  _id: 1,
  title: 1,
  settings: {
    $reduce: {
      input: "$settings",
      initialValue: [],
      in: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$$value",
          {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: ["$$this.status", "enabled"] },
              ["$$this.type"],
              []
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/t7RGZoQ9EDF)